# Getting system default ca certificates file in Python

Tags: python, certificate

Is there a Python method for requesting the path to the operating systems default CA Certificates file? In my Debian installations it is located at /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt, but I can't rely on this at other systems.